# Making Terminal Vim my default text editor. xfce4 FreeBSD

Tags: shell, vim, terminal, freebsd, xfce

I want to be able to double click a file and have it open in vim inside the terminal.

I can change the default application by right clicking and selecting "Open with another application" then "Use A custom command", and then using a shell script in a file I wrote... which is this

```
terminal -e vim
```

It works in that it opens vim in a terminal, but not the file i was selecting.

So how can I change the script so that it opens the files I select?

Comment: Can you not use gvim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply [create](http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/customize-menu#add_entries) a `vim.desktop` file.